# constant resident memory increase in golang with multiple concurrent tls dialers

Tags: go, concurrency

Alright so this has been plaguing me for weeks and I can't figure out what I'm missing or where this leak is or if it even exists. I have a fairly simple workload. Take a list of URLs, spin up a pool of goroutines that pull URLs from achannel and create a tls connection to them with tls.Dialer. Below is a snapshot of the memory graph showing the constant rise and a POC of my code.

My guess is it's something to do with the allocations done by the tls package because it seems to only climb the more "successful" URLs it connects to. I.E. if most of them don't connect I don't see a steady memory increase.

Here is a pprof output from midway through the run:

```
Showing nodes accounting for 190.70MB, 95.58% of 199.53MB total
Dropped 34 nodes (cum <= 1MB)
Showing top 20 nodes out of 77
   flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
   51.52MB 25.82% 25.82%    51.52MB 25.82%  runtime.malg
   24.10MB 12.08% 37.90%    24.10MB 12.08%  bytes.makeSlice
   17.07MB  8.55% 46.45%    41.17MB 20.63%  crypto/tls.(*Conn).readHandshake
   15MB  7.52% 53.97%    78.85MB 39.52%  crypto/tls.dial
   11MB  5.51% 59.48%    11.50MB  5.76%  net.(*netFD).connect
   10MB  5.01% 64.50%    15.42MB  7.73%  context.WithDeadline
   9MB  4.51% 69.01%        9MB  4.51%  net.newFD (inline)
   8MB  4.01% 73.02%    10.84MB  5.43%  time.AfterFunc
   7MB  3.51% 76.53%    52.93MB 26.53%  net.(*Dialer).DialContext
   5.50MB  2.76% 79.28%     5.50MB  2.76%  context.(*cancelCtx).Done
   5MB  2.51% 81.79%    84.35MB 42.28%  main.main.func3
   5MB  2.51% 84.30%        5MB  2.51%  net.(*netFD).connect.func2
   4.50MB  2.26% 86.55%     4.50MB  2.26%  time.goFunc
   4MB  2.01% 88.56%        4MB  2.01%  crypto/tls.Client (inline)
   3.16MB  1.58% 90.14%     3.16MB  1.58%  main.main
   2.84MB  1.42% 91.56%     2.84MB  1.42%  time.startTimer
   2.50MB  1.25% 92.82%     2.50MB  1.25%  crypto/aes.(*aesCipherGCM).NewGCM
   2.50MB  1.25% 94.07%     2.50MB  1.25%  net.(*Resolver).internetAddrList.func1
   1.50MB  0.75% 94.82%     1.50MB  0.75%  crypto/tls.(*Config).Clone
   1.50MB  0.75% 95.58%     1.50MB  0.75%  crypto/aes.newCipher
```

[image: steady increase in memory]

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "net"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func connectToTarget(targetString string, dialer *net.Dialer, config *tls.Config) {
    tConn, err := tls.DialWithDialer(dialer,"tcp", targetString, config)
    if err == nil {
        //do something with connection
        tConn.Close()
    }
}

func main() {
    workers := 256 * 256 //65536
    tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
        InsecureSkipVerify: true,
    }
    dialer := &net.Dialer{
        FallbackDelay: -1,
        KeepAlive:     -1,
        Timeout:       time.Duration(60) * time.Second,
    }

    targetsChan := make(chan string, workers)
    var workerDone sync.WaitGroup
    workerDone.Add(workers)

    for i := 0; i < workers; i++ {
        go func(functionWg *sync.WaitGroup, dialer *net.Dialer, tlsConfig *tls.Config, targets chan string) {
            for targetToConnect := range targets {
                connectToTarget(targetToConnect, dialer, tlsConfig)
            }

            functionWg.Done()
        }(&workerDone, dialer, tlsConfig,targetsChan)
    }

    targets := []string{} //in the actual code this reads from a file containing the list since it is large
    for _,target := range targets {
        targetsChan <- target
    }


    close(targetsChan)
    workerDone.Wait()
}
```

*UPDATE*:

Here is the first pprof (taken 10 minutes in) compared to that last one I took which was after it had been steadily climbing for a while.

```
Showing nodes accounting for 329.76MB, 83.32% of 395.77MB total
Dropped 57 nodes (cum <= 1.98MB)
  flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
  199.43MB 50.39% 50.39%   199.43MB 50.39%  bytes.makeSlice
  80.80MB 20.42% 70.81%   280.22MB 70.80%  crypto/tls.(*Conn).readHandshake
  28.02MB  7.08% 77.89%    28.02MB  7.08%  crypto/tls.Client (inline)
  18.01MB  4.55% 82.44%    18.01MB  4.55%  crypto/aes.(*aesCipherGCM).NewGCM
  11MB  2.78% 85.22%       11MB  2.78%  crypto/aes.newCipher
  9.50MB  2.40% 87.62%     9.50MB  2.40%  crypto/tls.(*Config).Clone
  -8MB  2.02% 85.60%    15.53MB  3.92%  crypto/tls.dial
  -5.50MB  1.39% 84.21%    -5.50MB  1.39%  net.(*netFD).connect
  -5MB  1.26% 82.94%    -5.50MB  1.39%  context.WithDeadline
  -4.50MB  1.14% 81.81%   -11.50MB  2.91%  net.(*Dialer).DialContext
  3.50MB  0.88% 82.69%     3.50MB  0.88%  net.sockaddrToTCP
  -3MB  0.76% 81.93%       -3MB  0.76%  time.AfterFunc
   2MB  0.51% 82.44%    17.53MB  4.43%  main.serverCert
   1.50MB  0.38% 82.82%        2MB  0.51%  crypto/tls.(*cipherSuiteTLS13).expandLabel
   1MB  0.25% 83.07%       18MB  4.55%  crypto/tls.aeadAESGCM
   1MB  0.25% 83.32%       10MB  2.53%  crypto/tls.aeadAESGCMTLS13
   0.50MB  0.13% 83.45%   201.93MB 51.02%  crypto/tls.(*Conn).readRecordOrCCS
   -0.50MB  0.13% 83.32%       -2MB  0.51%  net.(*sysDialer).dialSingle
   0     0% 83.32%   118.09MB 29.84%  bytes.(*Buffer).Grow (inline)
   0     0% 83.32%    81.33MB 20.55%  bytes.(*Buffer).Write
   0     0% 83.32%   199.43MB 50.39%  bytes.(*Buffer).grow
   0     0% 83.32%       11MB  2.78%  crypto/aes.NewCipher
   0     0% 83.32%    18.01MB  4.55%  crypto/cipher.NewGCM (inline)
   0     0% 83.32%    18.01MB  4.55%  crypto/cipher.newGCMWithNonceAndTagSize
   0     0% 83.32%   318.24MB 80.41%  crypto/tls.(*Conn).Handshake
   0     0% 83.32%   318.24MB 80.41%  crypto/tls.(*Conn).clientHandshake
   0     0% 83.32%     3.01MB  0.76%  crypto/tls.(*Conn).readChangeCipherSpec (inline)
   0     0% 83.32%   118.09MB 29.84%  crypto/tls.(*Conn).readFromUntil
   0     0% 83.32%   198.92MB 50.26%  crypto/tls.(*Conn).readRecord (inline)
   0     0% 83.32%    11.58MB  2.93%  crypto/tls.(*Conn).retryReadRecord
   0     0% 83.32%   154.61MB 39.06%  crypto/tls.(*clientHandshakeState).doFullHandshake
   0     0% 83.32%    22.51MB  5.69%  crypto/tls.(*clientHandshakeState).establishKeys
   0     0% 83.32%   180.12MB 45.51%  crypto/tls.(*clientHandshakeState).handshake
   0     0% 83.32%     3.01MB  0.76%  crypto/tls.(*clientHandshakeState).readFinished
   0     0% 83.32%       12MB  3.03%  crypto/tls.(*clientHandshakeStateTLS13).establishHandshakeKeys
   0     0% 83.32%   117.50MB 29.69%  crypto/tls.(*clientHandshakeStateTLS13).handshake
   0     0% 83.32%    92.92MB 23.48%  crypto/tls.(*clientHandshakeStateTLS13).readServerCertificate
   0     0% 83.32%    11.58MB  2.93%  crypto/tls.(*clientHandshakeStateTLS13).readServerParameters
   0     0% 83.32%    10.50MB  2.65%  crypto/tls.(*halfConn).setTrafficSecret
   0     0% 83.32%    15.53MB  3.92%  crypto/tls.DialWithDialer (inline)
   0     0% 83.32%        3MB  0.76%  crypto/tls.cipherAES
   0     0% 83.32%   318.24MB 80.41%  crypto/tls.dial.func2
   0     0% 83.32%    17.53MB  4.43%  main.main.func3
   0     0% 83.32%       -2MB  0.51%  net.(*sysDialer).dialSerial
   0     0% 83.32%       -2MB  0.51%  net.internetSocket
   0     0% 83.32%       -2MB  0.51%  net.socket
```

Here is a flame graph of the same data:
[image: flame graph comparing two pprof heap dumps]

The biggest offender is bytes.makeSlice which is called during handshake reads. This *could* mean that every time the goroutines make a new `tls.DialWithDialer` to connect to a URL the buffers are being held onto. This would be a surprise to me because I would expect the `Close()` method to evict those buffers.

Comment: 65536 is really a lot of workers. It could take a while before each of them "gets going" (and starts allocating more memory), since they're competing for resources such as net bandwidth. Also, how large is your file, and how are you reading it in?

Comment: Hmm, lowering the workers would definitely lower the total memory used just due to less goroutines but it still leaves the mystery of why it's growing. Even a lot of them I would expect to eventually plateau. I used some to see what the goroutines were doing and none are sitting around waiting to do anything so I think they "get going" right away, The file is about ~7877302 URLs, I am using a bufio.Scanner sending to a channel.

Comment: Why do you need to  wait for initializing all 65536 worker goroutines before start sending in the string to the channel?

Comment: I'm a bit curious about why you say "http clients", because you are not using http clients, but using tls, which is a  layer below https. The http package employs tls automatically when performing Get requests.

Comment: http clients is incorrect I agree, sorry about that. I don't actually need the bytes from the response at all just the data from the successful tls connection so I went a level lower to just create the tls connection. I'll reword the question.

Comment: @Rengas I don't need to that's just how I wrote it. You could do it in the reverse as well. I could be wrong but I don't think that it's the cause of the issue to init the goroutines then send them data.

Comment: I see in your pprof `runtime.malg` taking up the most amount of memory. It creates memory for newly created goroutine and holds reference until the goroutine finish executing. The channels are closed only at end. Since goroutines has the reference to the channel, so the references created by runtime.malg could be held in the memory till the channel gets closed.

Comment: The description above `runtime.malg` is: "Allocate a new g, with a stack big enough for stacksize bytes." To me, this sounds like it's just the memory for the stack of each goroutine, which I think would be impossible to bypass in terms of allocation.

Comment: Use the `-base` option for pprof to compare two profiles. This will show you exactly where additional memory goes. Make sure you're looking at one of the in-use profiles (`-inuse_space`, for instance), and not alloc profiles (the default).

Comment: @Peter I added the base compare of two heap dumps taken about an hour apart after steady memory rise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the code in `//do something with connection` was more important than I thought. Even at the tls.Dial level you have to read off the "body". My, now obviously wrong assumption, was that tls.Dial just setup the connection and that since a `GET / HTTP 1.1` request hadn't been sent yet no data needed to be read off the wire. This was causing all those buffers full of server response to sit around.

`_, _= ioutil.ReadAll(tConn)` fixed it all in one line. I feel much wiser and also dumb at the same time. As a side note, at this level, `ReadAll()` can hang for a long time if the server responds slowly. `tConn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(time.Second * timeout))` solved that too.